# MySQL query / PHP print values if match

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have made a sql query to fetch how many values exists for each color.
This is the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT Color, count(Color) as Total FROM table WHERE (Color !='Red' AND Color !='White' AND Color !='Blu') GROUP BY Color ORDER By Total DESC";
```

This is the output of the query:

```
+--------+-------+
| Color  | Total |
+--------+-------+
| Orange |  2471 |
| Yellow |   337 |
| Black  |    82 |
+--------+-------+
```

Well now I would like to print in PHP the "Total" value "IF" the Color is Orange, or Yellow, etc...

Example:
if Color=Orange I should see "2471"
if Color=Yellow I should see "337"
etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$color="Orange";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    if($row['Color']==$color){
        echo $row['Total'];
    }
}
?>
```